# Why does WifiManager.addNetwork return a network ID but then will not connect

Tags: android, wifi

I am using WifiManager to connect to a network or actually a device.  It was working perfectly and then all of sudden stopped, with no code changes.  I did start using a different phone.  I've checked and I believe the phone is setup properly.  When I call addNetwork I get a network ID back that is different from the current network ID.  When I run enableNetwork, passing it the network ID returned by addNetwork, I do not get an error but when I check the connection info I am still connected to the original network.  The device I'm connecting to does not require a user or password.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me.

I've tried doing a reconnect right after the enable network and I've tried disconnecting from the current network before connecting to the new one.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

public class DeviceConnect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public interface AsyncResponse {
        void processFinish(String output);
    }

    public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

    public DeviceConnect(AsyncResponse delegate){
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    private Context _context = null;
    private String _result = null;
    private WiFiHandler _wifiHandler = null;

    public void setContext(Context value) {
        this._context = value;
    }
    public String getResult() {
        return this._result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String message = null;
        boolean ok = true;
        String device = params[0];
        this._result = null;

        this._wifiHandler = new WiFiHandler();
        if (!device.isEmpty()) {
            int netID = 0;
            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) this._context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiConfiguration config;
            WifiInfo connInfo;

            config = new WifiConfiguration();
            config.SSID = device;
            wifi.disconnect();
            netID = wifi.addNetwork(config);
Log.e("doInBackground", "netID: " + netID);
            if (netID > 0) {
                try {
                    wifi.enableNetwork(netID, true);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ok = false;
                    this._result = device + " - Add network failed (2)";
                }
                if(ok) {
                    connInfo = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
Log.e("doInBackground", connInfo.getSSID() + " - " + connInfo.getNetworkId());
                    if (connInfo != null && connInfo.getSSID().equalsIgnoreCase(device)) {  // || (netID = connInfo.getNetworkId()) <= 0) {
                        this._result = "SUCCESS";
                    } else {
                        this._result = device + " - Add device failed (3)";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                this._result = device + " - Add device failed (1)";
            }
        } else {
            this._result = "No device to configure";
        }

        return this._result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(String result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

It should connect to the device and return "SUCCESS".  For what I need to do I will only be connected to the device for a matter of a second or so.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying and failing I finally found the answer.  It was apparently a timing issue.  The code below solved my problem.

```
            Object lock = new Object();
            lock = wifi.enableNetwork(netID, true);
            synchronized(lock) {
                lock.wait(500);
            }
```

Comment: Can you explain why does it work? It seems that just blocking the thread